# Выравнивание блока div по центру

Tags: html, css

Как я могу выровнять по центру картинку внутри блока `<div>`?

```css
#div1 img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/200' alt='image' />
</div>
```

Comment: `#div1 { text-align: center; }`

Comment: @andreymal это центрирование по горизонтали, а как сделать по вертикали?

Comment: Смотря как нужно отцентрировать https://jsfiddle.net/3txc1unL/

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex да, именно так и нужно было. Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

display + margin :

```css
#block {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#block img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='block'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/200' alt='image'/>
</div>
```

position + transform:

```css
#block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
#block img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='block'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/200' alt='image'/>
</div>
```

flexbox:

```css
#block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex; /* display: grid; */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='block'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/200' alt='image'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, сделал в итоге так:

```html
<div>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/200' alt='image'/>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```